# Using EF 6.0.1 in VS2013 projects

Tags: entity-framework

I have a clean install of VS2013. I understand this shipped with EF 6.0.0 and that there is now a runtime update known as 6.0.1. How do I make sure that is the version used on new projects? Should the reference show a version number of 6.0.1 in its properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a NuGet update in a new project for Entity Framework and it now shows in `packages.config`

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

If you don't like updating this package on new projects you'll have to create a new project template after you have updated EF in a new empty solution.

Since EF or other included packages are frequently updated I wouldn't bother with a new template. Instead, I would manually update to be sure I have the latest after creating a new project -- I would check for updates anyway even if I had an "updated project template".

Comment: Thank you. I followed your instructions and it worked just as you said, no problem. But let me ask one more thing, while packages.config was changed my app.config still contains the record <section name="entityFramework"type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />. Should the Version parameter in app.config also be changed or is this referring to something else? Thanks.

Comment: That's a good question. But if you look in the physical dll location (e.g. project/bin) and examine the file you can see _File Version_ and _Product Version_. After updating, I see _File Version: 6.0.21010.0_ and _Product Version: 6.0.1-21010_.